# Why is a clock necessary for the logoot approach?

Tags: p2p, collaborative-editing, crdt

I am planning a P2P collaborative editing software and I was planning on going with WOOT. The problem would have been that I would have had loads and loads of tombstones (atoms are characters...) so I searched more and found [this PDF about the Logoot approach](https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00336191/PDF/main.pdf). Everything is clear to me apart from one thing: why does every site need a clock? I couldn't find anything in the document that mentions the purpose of this value.

Is there a situation which requires a clock to be solved without conflict?

Answer (score 2):

I was wondering this too. Not an official source, but according to the docs for npm's [logoot package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/logoot):

> Note that vector clock values are not compared. Vector clock values
>   are used to ensure unique atom identifiers, not for ordering.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a situation which requires a clock to be solved without conflict?

There is, and it took me way more time to realize that than i'm willing to admit:

Say we have an array `A` = [`P`] (where `P` is logoot position) and two clients `C1` and `C2`.
`C1` does this: delete(`P`), insert(`P`); local `A` = [`P`]
`C2` does this: delete(`P`);              local `A` = []

after `C2` applies `C1` operations it gets `A` = [`P`]
after `C1` applies `C2` operations it gets `A` = []
Oops.

Since logoot doesn't use tombstones a client could generate a position it itself deleted before, thus you need `clock` to avoid aforementioned situation.